# Error: Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 206. when using Kpfonts-otf

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec, kpfonts

This is my MWE:

```
% !TeX program = xelatex
\documentclass[12pt, parskip]{scrreport}

\usepackage[symbols]{kpfonts-otf}
\setmainfont{KpRoman}

\begin{document}
Hello!
\end{document}
```

When I compile it using `XeLaTeX` I get the following error message:

```
Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 206.
```

However, if I switch

```
\usepackage[symbols]{kpfonts-otf}
\setmainfont{KpRoman}
```

to

```
\usepackage{kpfonts-otf}
```

then everything is fine.

But I really want to use the former one since I want to use some options with `\setmathfont` (which is not included in my MWE).

How can I fix this?

Comment: it is not fine without the option, you only don't get an error, but the log-file reports then `(\end occurred when \ifx on line 218 was incomplete)`. There is a `\fi` missing on line 267. Report it to the author, he is normally fast in fixing things.

Comment: The bug has been fixed with `kpfonts-otf` version 0.56

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be reported to the author of the package, it's missing `\fi` on line 270

```
  \fi
\fi
\fi%<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<missing
\ifkp@symbols
```

Comment: I emailed  Daniel

Comment: Thanks, David and Ulrike! bug is fixed in version 0.56 which is on its way to CTAN.